# Exception guarrantees and fast push_back

Tags: c++, c++11

As pointed out by Scott Meyers (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler on 00.34.45) only if a class's move functions are declared non throwing (preferably with noexcept) and only then, vector::push_back() can use move semantics.

So what are the exception specifications of a class's compiler generated move functions and if no strong exception guarantee is provided, does it mean that I get no optimization from move semantics in C++11 push_back() and other similar methods?

Comment: As the compiler-generated (defaulted) move functions are member-wise moves, it depends on the members which exception safety guarantee is implicitly given, and whether the function is noexcept or not. Also, `vector` will use move semantics when the copy ctor of the element type cannot be called (e.g. deleted or private).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception specifications for implicitly generated moves (as well as implicit copies and inherited constructors) are detailed in 15.4/14:

> An inheriting constructor (12.9) and an implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) have an *exception-specification*. If `f` is an inheriting constructor or an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit *exception-specification* specifies the *type-id* `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the *exception-specification* of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` has the *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions. [ *Note:* It follows that `f` has the *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if it invokes no other functions. —end note ] [ *Note:* An instantiation of an inheriting constructor template has an implied *exception-specification* as if it were a non-template inheriting constructor. —end note ]

Whew.

So the compiler effectively declares the implicit moves for your class as possibly throwing the union of whatever exceptions each of the member-wise moves is declared to throw. If they are all `noexcept`, your class's move is `noexcept` as well.

You are correct that things like `vector` reallocation will prefer to copy a type when the type is copyable and its move operations may throw. For this reason, it's a very good idea to design for `noexcept` move construction and assignment of classes that you plan to store in containers.